# Java Bean ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, javabeans

I have an ArrayList of Strings in my java bean.  I want to be able to add/remove from this list at design time in the property editor.  How do I implement this?  I am coming back to Java after like 5 years so I'm a little stupid.  I have managed to get all my simple type properties to be editable in the editor, but this property, when you click the "..." in the property editor, it says that custom editing is not supported for that type.
So...
Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: Please define "in the property editor".

Comment: Property editor in the GUI Designer sorry.  (NetBeans).  I need to make this a re-usable control and the arraylist is a list of restricted values that the person using my control can define at design-time.

Answer (score 1):

Mmm... Do you means this?

```
import java.util.List;

public MyBean {

private List<String> stringList;

public void add(String str) {
    stringList.add(str);
}

public String get(int i) {
    return stringList.get(i);
}

public String[] getElements() {
    String[] elements;
    stringList.toArray(elements);        
    return elements;
}

// ... Your bean struct here

}
```

or you need [this (JList)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

Comment: This solution does not do what I need to do.  I need to make it so items can be added to and removed from this arraylist in the designer.  like when you click one the "..." button and can specify values, I need to know how this is done for an Arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the [Java Beans Spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) does not mention Collections of any kind, however it supports Arrays as "Indexed Properties".

The pattern is:

```
Type[] getFoo();
void setFoo(Type[] value);
Type getFoo(int index);
void setFoo(int index, Type[] value);
```

Popular components like JList and JTree get around this limitation by implementing a model (which is technically just a property) and a custom component editor to visually edit the model.

There is a [java trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/advanced/customization.html) for custom editors which explains this in detail.
I am unsure whether it is possible to create an editor for a get/set property of type `ArrayList<T>`, but probably that is also possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TheBean {
    private List strings = ....

getStrings(){
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.strings) // so if you return the reference people cant muck with it.
}

addListElement(String toAdd) {
    // possibly validate toAdd
    this.strings.add(toAdd);
}
// you also need removeListelement
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Im not sure what you mean by property editor.  Are you talking about an IDE?

In any event, if your List is private, you have 2 options for allowing access to it.

1)  Return a reference to the list, which a caller can then operate on.
2)  Create a method add/removeListElement, and pass in the Strings you want to add or remove.

I like option 2 better, because it provides better encapsulation/data hiding of the List.

Something like the following, which is pseudo but you get the idea....

```
class TheBean {
    private List strings = ....

    getStrings(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.strings) // so if you return the reference people cant muck with it.
    }

    addListElement(String toAdd) {
        // possibly validate toAdd
        this.strings.add(toAdd);
    }
    // you also need removeListelement
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry, the project requires me to use Netbeans, so I am.  I need the property editor for the GUI designer to allow the client to add/remove members to this array list in the GUI designer without any coding.

Comment: I am creating a re-usable user control if it helps